# Belkin HDMI to VGA adapter not displaying / not detected

Tags: 16.04, display, hdmi, xrandr, adapter

I purchased a Belkin HDMI to VGA adapter (also carries Audio). I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 (Gnome) on a 15" Macbook Pro Late 2013 Model (DMI: Apple Inc. MacBookPro11,3/Mac-2BD1B31983FE1663, BIOS MBP112.88Z.0138.B17.1602221600 02/22/2016).

When I plug in the adapter to my HDMI port, the screens briefly switch off (as it detects the new output, as usual), but afterward the screen does not operate, it simply goes to sleep. The gnome display settings, as well as xrandr do not detect any display present on the HDMI port.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
    $xrandr
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4480 x 1800, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 1600x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 367mm x 275mm
   1600x1200     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected 2880x1800+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   2880x1800     59.99*+
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
    $lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Crystal Well DRAM Controller (rev 08)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Crystal Well PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 08)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Crystal Well PCI Express x8 Controller (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 750M Mac Edition] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
04:00.0 Multimedia controller: Broadcom Corporation 720p FaceTime HD Camera
05:00.0 SATA controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Apple PCIe SSD (rev 01)
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
07:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
07:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
07:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
07:05.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
07:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
08:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation DSL5520 Thunderbolt [Falcon Ridge]
09:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge]
0a:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL3510 Thunderbolt Controller [Cactus Ridge]
0b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57762 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
```

Answer (score 1):

Supply power to the USB port on the adapter may be the cause.
You may be using a low-power HDMI device, in which case you may need to provide additional power to the HDMI adapter by using a Micro-USB cable to a USB wall charger with at least 500 mA minimum output.